# pycharm running unittests stopped working

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

For some unknown reason my pycharm has stopped successfully running unittests. Before I could simply right click a file of tests and hit Debug unittests in.. 
or in the file itself call for debugging on the TestCase subclass itself or on any test_ method thereof.  Now it just finishes immediately with nothing and creates an artifact in configurations that seems to be treating the unitest file as a simple python file.   If I delete that I sometimes get in a weird state where it fails a bunch of assertions immediately and tries to user my path to the file as a module somehow by the error it puts out.

I don't understand.  I have used pycharm for years and never seen this problem previously.

Looks to be the 2019.2 version running on Ubuntu.  Did something change?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! The project having the problem was opened via a soft link directory.  When I opened the same thing using the direct directory the problem disappeared.  Bizarre.